# Is there a way to filter with AWS SNS filter policies from the message body to SQS queues?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a general question about SNS filter policies. I know that the filter policies filter based on the Message Attributes. If we wanted to filter based on the body, is there a work around to do so?

The SNS topic will be delivering different types of data to SQS queues based on the filter policies.

Comment: No, you filter on the message attributes. You *can* build some itermediary lambda that consumes the messages, transforms them, puts more data into the message attributes and publishes those messages again.

Comment: Thank you! That doesn't seem worth it does it? It sounds it could make things more complex

Comment: you need to send message attribute while sending message so that that filter policy can be applied . it does not work directly on body .  i feel you should use sns message attribute to filter.  let me know if you have further queries.

Comment: Yes, look at the "FilterPolicyScope" property of the SNS Subscription resource and set that to "MessageBody"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is now a property called "FilterPolicyScope" in the SNS Subscription resource which, if set to "MessageBody" instead of "MessageAttributes" the default, will apply the Filter Policy to the message body.

More information and an example of how you can filter on fields in the s3 event being passed to SNS [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-payload-based-message-filtering-for-amazon-sns/)